# Remove premium command not working for me

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import os
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands, check

@bot.command()
async def removepremium(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.id != 475975102576590849: #put your user id on discord here
        return

    with open("premium_users.json") as f:
        premium_users_list = json.load(f)

    if user.id in premium_users_list:
      premium_users_list.pop(user.id)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} is not in the list, so they cannot be removed!")
        return

    with open("premium_users.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(premium_users_list, f)

    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has been removed!")
```

removepremium is not working i am getting this error -

Ignoring exception in command removepremium:
File "main.py", line 247, in removepremium
premium_users_list.pop(user.id)
IndexError: pop index out of range

Answer (score 0):

`list.pop(N)` [method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-pop/#:%7E:text=pop()%20is%20an%20inbuilt,or%20the%20given%20index%20value.&text=Parameter%20%3A,is%20popped%20out%20and%20removed.) removes from list `N`th element.

```py
a = ["a","b","c"]
a.pop(1)
print(a)
```

> `['a', 'c']`

When you trying to `premium_users_list.pop(user.id)` do you actually want to remove user with exact `ID` or remove user that position in list is `ID`?

I don't know what is your JSON data, so try to explain your code behaviour with my example:

```py
>>> users = [{"id": 100, "name": "A"}, {"id": 101, "name": "A"}, {"id": 102, "name": "A"}]
>>> 
>>> users.pop(101)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range
>>> 
>>> users.pop(1)
{'id': 101, 'name': 'A'}
>>> 
>>> print(users)
[{'id': 100, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 102, 'name': 'A'}]
```

If you want to delete user with `ID = 101` you should do something like:

```py
>>> users = [{"id": 100, "name": "A"}, {"id": 101, "name": "A"}, {"id": 102, "name": "A"}]
>>> 
>>> users_without_101 = [i for i in users if not i['id'] == 101]
>>> 
>>> print(users_without_101)
[{'id': 100, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 102, 'name': 'A'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is change .pop to .remove

premium_users_list.remove(user.id)